# How to Initialize state array in Main()

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, validation, program-entry-point

The problem is that I am not sure how to properly format the code so that when the user enters a State Abbreviation the main method looks for it in the GetValidState method to let the user know whether what they entered is valid or not. One of the key things is that the abbreviation must be 2 letters long.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string stateAbbreviation;
    bool fieldValidationSuccess = false;

    promt = GetValidState("State (2 letters):\t");
    stateAbbreviation = ReadLine();
}

public static string GetValidState(string prompt, string[] sortedStateArray)
{
    string[] states = new string[] { "AK", "WA", "OR", "CA", "AZ", "NM", "CO", "UT" };

    fieldValidationSuccess = false;

    while (!fieldValidationSuccess)
    {
        int sub = 0;
        while (sub < states.Length && !fieldValidationSuccess)
        {
            if (states[sub].ToUpper() == stateAbbreviation.ToUpper())
            {
                fieldValidationSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sub++;
            }
        }

        if (!fieldValidationSuccess)
        {
            WriteLine("\n***ERROR.  We do not ship to {0}.", stateAbbreviation);
        }
    }
}
```

- Initialize the state array in Main().

• Build a validation loop to ensure that the user enters a valid state abbreviation.

• Use a loop to search the array for a valid state. Do not use Array.BinarySearch

• Call GetValidString to get the string from the user. Use 2 for both the min and max parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The bullet list at the end looks like a homework assignment. Is that what this is?

Comment: `stateAbbreviation` is defined locally inside the `Main` method. Perhaps you should move that line to the `GetValidState` method instead, where you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. You want a code to check if the STATE is in your Array?

```cs
        public static void GetValidState(string prompt, string state)
        {
            string[] states = new string[] { "AK", "WA", "OR", "CA", "AZ", "NM", "CO", "UT" };

            if (!states.Contains(state))
                WriteLine("\n***ERROR.  We do not ship to {0}.", state);

        }
```